# How to insert a TRUE BLANK with Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use the following function to create an invoice.

```
=VSTACK(FILTER(PerformedTestsTable9,PerformedTestsTable9[Qty]>0,), {"","","Total sum to be paid:"})
```

Very simple, filtered table for Qty > 1 plus added row with VSTACK.

However every time I change something in the source table I get "Total sum to be paid:" left aligned in the bottom right cell, as in the following screenshot:

[image]

One can see the bold text below is how I want it to look like - it was added manually.

If I then use Calculation event that triggers a VBA procedure, which looks for the last row and right aligns the last cell I get:

[image]

That implies that the adjacent cell to the bottom right cell is not blank. In contrast to the adjacent cell of the manually added text below.

So my question is:
How do I insert a TRUE BLANK with an Excel formula?

Comment: I don't understand your hypothesized link between the result of a formula and cell alignment. Text is by default left-aligned. And perhaps you could clarify your statement "*That implies that the adjacent cell to the bottom right cell is not blank*"? How so?

Comment: A formula can never insert what you consider a 'true' blank. A null string is the closest approximation, though a null string is not equivalent to empty.

Comment: You already answered the question - it can not be done!

Comment: The statement "That implies that the adjacent cell to the bottom right cell is not blank" means the following: If a cell to the right (in a left-aligned cell) or to the left (in a right-aligned cell) is blank that the text that does not fit into a cell will "spill" over into adjacent cell (as you can see in the manually added bold text).

Comment: Very poor on Excels part. If I was able to fish it out, in what is basically a hobby project, I can not imagine that it has not bothered others that rely heavily on Excel.